# How to differentiate Package for a page publish and publish a bundle with a page?

Tags: publishing, bundles

How does a package change in terms of "publishing a single page" and "Publishing a bundle with a single page"?
Also, how does the package change when "publishing a bundle with a page AND a dynamic component"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the package will have any difference, since you're still rendering a page or a DCP (there is a package instance for each rendering). If you need to render something differently based on this data, then you'll have to look at the PublishTransaction (accessible under `engine.PublishingContext.RenderContext.PublishTransaction`) - the `Items` property will contain the item that was sent to the publishing queue.

Comment: Oh! Is this the magic 'new' property that allows us to find the publish transaction from within the template without the 'dirty hack'? Is this 2013+ or 2011+?

Comment: 2013 SP1 for sure, not sure about GA.

Comment: Just checked on 2013 GA and it works there too.